# how can i achieve drag n drop for grouping in Angularjs ui-grid module

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have used ng-grid there we had drag n drop feature for grid column grouping but now in ui-grid I couldn't find that feature.
is there any draw back to use drag n drop ?
or I have missed it
please let me know if there is already this feature is available . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am thinking to create  my own plugin as feature in angular-ui-grid for group drag n drop. will it be good idea to add JqueryUI draggable as directive in ui-grid feature? or Is there better component for drag n drop?

Comment: I am very interested in a feature like this. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @davaus  I didn't start to work on this feature yet for time being I am using agGrid that is also built on AngularJS. it has feature for drag n drop grouping. But it is paid. Next week I am planning to start work on my feature for angular-ui-grid.